# Assembly - bit mask for non power of two intervals

Tags: assembly, binary, boolean-logic, mips64

I have an array of integers in the [0,5000) range and I want to split them in 5 intervals ([0,1000), [1000,2000), ..., [4000,5000)) in assembly. I used an approach which although correct has room for improvement :

```
sltiu $t2, $t0, 1000 ; array element in $t0, compare to 1000
;...
bne $t2, $zero, condition ; if $t0 was in the interval done
```

and going thusly for the rest. This results in, at worst, 5 branches with all kinds of unavoidable stalls. I would like to go for an approach where I would apply a mask to the array element which would result in a different bit pattern depending on if the value belongs to the intervals of interest. Then I would use the value of the bit pattern to jump into an array position (reserved with `.space`) where I'd put a +1 for the relevant interval (pseudocode):

```
daddi $v0, $zero, array_of_interval_hits
; loop
xor $t3, $t0, mask   ; $t0 contains the array element
lwu $t4,  array_of_interval_hits($t3)
daddi $t4, $t4, 1
sw $t4, array_of_interval_hits($t3)
```

Is there such a mask ?

PS : if number >= 5000  or number < 0 I have to (print a message and) exit - using unsigned arithmetics I only care for the case number >= 5000 (negative numbers are big positives in 2's complement)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I do not think that such a mask exists - if anyone comes up with a solution please post and will accept but closing this for now (for my solution to my programming problem see my comment : [Assembly - bit mask for non power of two intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16508669/assembly-bit-mask-for-non-power-of-two-intervals#comment23741022_16508878))

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with mips assembly, so I won't get into specific machine instructions. My thought was to not use a mask, but to just divide (integer divide not floating point divide) your number by 1000. You could use the result `0, 1, 2, ...` to determine where to jump.

So for example numbers in the array between 0 - 999 would give a result of 0; array numbers 1000 - 1999 would give a result of 1; etc.

To deal with your PS - Any negative result (assuming signed divide operation) and you could jump to the proper handler. Same with any result of 5 or more.

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately a nono - division takes 24 cycles so it would blew performance totally :(. That's why I am trying to go for a mask

Comment: @Mr_and_Mrs_D - Interesting. So just for my understanding - 24 cycles is worse than "5 branches with all kinds of unavoidable stalls"?

Comment: yes :) I am at 1700 with my current implementation - this would blew it to over 2500 - to be fair I will try and compute it and get back to you ASAP

Comment: I did try an approach similar to what you say - but instead of dividing  I multiplied with a constant and then used a left shift - this approach is discussed [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/tech-board/155953-optimization-issues-minimize-branches.html) and my code is [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/tech-board/155953-optimization-issues-minimize-branches-2.html#post1162774) - 1200 cycles. Still if there were a mask of some sort the code would be much faster.